# How do I copy all "extra" data (menus, widgets, etc) from one theme to another?

Tags: customization, themes

I have two copies of a theme I'm developing up on my site (one was the existing file structure when I got started; the other is now set up to update automatically via git for a more sane development cycle).

When I switch between themes, I lose customizations I'd done on the site (menu, logo, etc). Given that I'm moving between *identical* themes, I assume there must be a way to transfer my set-up between versions of the theme exactly, either by copying some config files, modifying the name of something, or moving things between items in the database.

Can someone tell me where wordpress keeps the data created when you go to "customize" a theme and how I can most effectively copy it between my old set-up and my new one?

Comment: These values are stored in options called theme mods e.g. `get_theme_mod()` vs `get_option()`, the answer to this question will involve these. Can we assume the menus and sidebars for each theme are named the same?

Comment: We can -- the "two" themes are two versions of the same codebase.

I seem to have found a workaround by renaming the theme folders in question so that what's old is new and what's new is old -- not an elegant solution but a functional one for the timebeing.